# Cancel long running query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a long running query with many transactions(not nested), will SQL Server rollback everything if I'll cancel this query, or just last transaction?

Code like:

```
Begin tran
Update...1
Commit
Begin tran
Update...2
Commit
Begin tran
Update...3
Commit
```

Suppose `Update 1` finished and `Update 2` is running, what will happen if I'll cancel this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you begin and commit each transaction separately i.e. Explicit Transactions are used, the rollback will be restricted only to whichever one is running at the moment. The ones before it are already executed and data has been changed in DB.